# iOS Xcode App crashes after release to App Store but not when testing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, crash, crash-reports

I've had an app on the app store for about a month and then I recently uploaded an updated binary to the App Store, version 2.0. It uses SpriteKit and ever since that update every person who downloaded it got a crash upon startup (this was apparent in the customer reviews). So I went back through my code and realized that I forgot to change one of the code signing options to Distribution instead of developer. After archiving that new binary, 2.1, and waiting ANOTHER week to have it released again, version 2.1 crashed as well. My app has been down for 2 weeks now and I'm fed up with this. I made very minor changes including a line of code in the AppDelegate.m that allows the user to play their own music in the background:

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
  return YES;
  }

I am not super comfortable with Xcode and it is my first app. I get this crash report in iTunes Connect:

```
        Incident Identifier: A0DB04E6-A62B-46AB-8896-CE77A91064EF
        Hardware Model:      iPhone5,3
        Process:             PokeJump [831]
        Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/BB765A31-6028-429B-9939-                        F69DB8B62E85/PokeJump.app/PokeJump
        Identifier:          PokeJump.PokeJump
        Version:             2.0 (2.0)
        Code Type:           ARM (Native)
        Parent Process:      launchd [1]

        Date/Time:           2014-07-01 19:07:36.341 -0400
        OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
        Report Version:      104

        Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
        Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
        Triggered by Thread:  0

        Last Exception Backtrace:
        0   CoreFoundation                     0x2fe61f06 __exceptionPreprocess + 126
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                    0x3a5f8ce2 objc_exception_throw + 34
        2   CoreFoundation                     0x2fe61e48 +[NSException raise:format:] +                         108
        3   SpriteKit                          0x325a6c12 +[SKPlaySound             playSoundFileNamed:atPosition:waitForCompletion:] + 578
        4   SpriteKit                          0x3255f8ec +[SKAction(SKActions) playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:] + 60
        5   PokeJump                           0x000637de 0x0005a000 + 38878
        6   PokeJump                           0x0006177e 0x0005a000 + 30590
        7   PokeJump                           0x0006e080 0x0005a000 + 82048
        8   UIKit                              0x32695a4e -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 514
        9   UIKit                              0x3269580c -[UIViewController view] + 20
        10  UIKit                              0x327b5292 -[UIWindow handleStatusBarChangeFromHeight:toHeight:] + 690
        11  UIKit                              0x3271c432 +[UIWindow _noteStatusBarHeightChanged:oldHeight:forAutolayoutRootViewsOnly:] + 234
        12  UIKit                              0x3281cb2c __79-[UIApplication _setStatusBarHidden:animationParameters:changeApplicationFlag:]_block_invoke + 128
        13  UIKit                              0x326c6a36 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 486
        14  UIKit                              0x327ff33a +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:animations:completion:] + 66
        15  UIKit                              0x32741de6 -[UIApplication _setStatusBarHidden:animationParameters:changeApplicationFlag:] + 458
        16  UIKit                              0x3269c8fc -[UIApplication _updateCurrentStatusBarViewControllerAppearance] + 244
        17  UIKit                              0x32699d8e -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 230
        18  UIKit                              0x32703a4c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 56
        19  UIKit                              0x327006e0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1816
        20  UIKit                              0x326facc4 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 716
        21  UIKit                              0x32696c92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3546
        22  UIKit                              0x32695df4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
        23  UIKit                              0x326fa400 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 612
        24  GraphicsServices                   0x34d03b50 _PurpleEventCallback + 604
        25  GraphicsServices                   0x34d0373a PurpleEventCallback + 30
        26  CoreFoundation                     0x2fe2c842 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
        27  CoreFoundation                     0x2fe2c7de __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
        28  CoreFoundation                     0x2fe2afaa __CFRunLoopRun + 1402
        29  CoreFoundation                     0x2fd95764 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
        30  CoreFoundation                     0x2fd95546 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
        31  UIKit                              0x326f9626 -[UIApplication _run] + 758
        32  UIKit                              0x326f488c UIApplicationMain + 1132
        33  PokeJump                           0x0006e73e 0x0005a000 + 83774
        34  libdyld.dylib                      0x3aaf6ab2 tlv_initializer + 2

        Thread 0 Crashed:
        0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3abad1f0 __pthread_kill + 8
        1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3ac157b2 pthread_kill + 54
        2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ab5dff4 abort + 72
        3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39fac98a abort_message + 70
        4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39fc56e2 default_terminate_handler() + 250
        5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a5f8f7a _objc_terminate() + 190
        6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39fc31b0 std::__terminate(void
        7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39fc2d12 __cxa_rethrow + 98
        8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a5f8e2a objc_exception_rethrow + 38
        9   CoreFoundation                  0x2fd957da CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 638
        10  CoreFoundation                  0x2fd95546 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
        11  UIKit                           0x326f9626 -[UIApplication _run] + 758
        12  UIKit                           0x326f488c UIApplicationMain + 1132
        13  PokeJump                        0x0006e73e 0x5a000 + 83774
        14  libdyld.dylib                   0x3aaf6ab4 start + 0

        Thread 1:
        0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3ab9a804 kevent64 + 24
        1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3aae9050 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
        2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3aae32de _dispatch_mgr_thread + 34

        Thread 2:
        0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3abadc70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
        1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3ac12c1e _pthread_wqthread + 306
        2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3ac12ad8 start_wqthread + 4

        Thread 3:
        0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3abadc70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
        1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3ac12c1e _pthread_wqthread + 306
        2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3ac12ad8 start_wqthread + 4

        Thread 4:
        0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3ab9aa50 mach_msg_trap + 20
        1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3ab9a848 mach_msg + 36
        2   CoreFoundation                  0x2fe2c624 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
        3   CoreFoundation                  0x2fe2ad44 __CFRunLoopRun + 788
        4   CoreFoundation                  0x2fd95764 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
        5   CoreFoundation                  0x2fd95546 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
        6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2edfa45e GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 126
        7   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2edee8fc CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 176
        8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3ac14956 _pthread_body + 138
        9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3ac148c6 _pthread_start + 98
        10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3ac12ae4 thread_start + 4

        Thread 5:
        0   AudioToolbox                    0x2f74f7d4 CrashIfClientProvidedBogusAudioBufferList + 124
        1   AudioToolbox                    0x2f75e1d6 AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer + 250
        2   AudioToolbox                    0x2f81decc AUInputFormatConverter2::PullAndConvertInput(AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long&, AudioBufferList&, AudioStreamPacketDescription*, bool&) + 96
        3   AudioToolbox                    0x2f81da74 AUConverterBase::RenderBus(unsigned             long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 212
        4   AudioToolbox                    0x2f7518f4 AUBase::DoRenderBus(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, AUOutputElement*, unsigned long, AudioBufferList&) + 144
        5   AudioToolbox                    0x2f751744 AUBase::DoRender(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, AudioBufferList&) + 528
        6   AudioToolbox                    0x2f80d96c AURemoteIO::PerformIO(unsigned long, unsigned int, unsigned int, AudioTimeStamp const&, AudioTimeStamp const&, AudioBufferList const*, AudioBufferList*, int&) + 484
        7   AudioToolbox                    0x2f80e9b8 AURIOCallbackReceiver_PerformIO + 392
        8   AudioToolbox                    0x2f8050b2 _XPerformIO + 174
        9   AudioToolbox                    0x2f77264a mshMIGPerform + 122
        10  AudioToolbox                    0x2f7e1b28 MSHMIGDispatchMessage + 28
        11  AudioToolbox                    0x2f80dbe4 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 116
        12  AudioToolbox                    0x2f810cc4 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 4
        13  AudioToolbox                    0x2f74db38 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 208
        14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3ac14956 _pthread_body + 138
        15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3ac148c6 _pthread_start + 98
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3ac12ae4 thread_start + 4

        Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
```

I realize it says version 2.0 on this crash report but I am assuming both crashed for the same reason. I am desperate to find a fix for this and it frustrates me so much because it runs perfectly fine on all the simulators and on my iPad and iPhone when I run it when connected to my computer. Any help would mean a lot. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried installing the latest version over the first version that was working fine? I'm assuming you could get at it from your commit history.

Comment: Please symbolicate that crash report (see https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) and share the methods from your application which appear in the stack trace (lines 5-7). Without that information we're just guessing why your app crashes trying to play some sound file.

Comment: To trace the released App, Consider to use [Crashlytics](http://www.crashlytics.com). It's a very good solution and free!. I don't think that the signing was a problem. If it was, your app couldn't pass the apple's review. Is your app still working on simulator?

Comment: Is your app's deploy target 7.0?

Comment: I fixed the problem. There was a method hat was calling a sound file that I deleted from Xcode